# Attribute code in related products

Tags: attributes, related-products, multiselect-attribute

I am using `$_item->getData("attribute_code")` to fetch the attribute code in the related products on the product page, but it does not seem to work with multiselect attributes.
Is there a variation on the code that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For getting values from select or multi-select, you need to use below code,

```
echo $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
```

or

```
echo implode(", ",$_item->getAttributeText('attribute_code'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I used `<?php echo $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item); ?>` and it works for other attributes but not for multiselect.

Comment: please check updated answer also make sure your attribute is visible on list page

Comment: It is visible on the list page

Comment: Are you using default related product block? I have checked the same code and found its working. Also please add your magento version to your question.